# Changing state of to do list tasks with Backbone in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm very new to Backbone and I'm making a to do list app to learn the basics. Right now you can add a task and it is rendered in the to do list. Each task has the properties name (string) and complete(boolean). I'd like to make it so that when the checkbox (.toggle) is checked, the 'complete' property is changed to true. I also have an 'x' button (.destroy), that when clicked should remove the task from the database. I'm having trouble getting the markComplete and clear events to work correctly. Here's my tasks_index.js.coffee view:

```
class Backbonetodo.Views.TasksIndex extends Backbone.View

template: JST['tasks/index']

events:
  'submit #new_task': 'createTask'
  'click .toggle': 'markComplete'
  'click .destroy': 'clear'

#I'd like this to change complete to true and put a line through the list item
markComplete: ->
 @collection.set(complete:true)

initialize: ->
  @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
  @collection.on('add', @appendTask, this)


render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template())
  @collection.each(@appendTask)
  this

appendTask: (task) ->
  view = new Backbonetodo.Views.Task(model: task)
  $('#tasks').append(view.render().el)

createTask: (task) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  attributes = name: $('#new_task_name').val()
  @collection.create attributes,
    wait: true
    success: -> $('#new_task')[0].reset()
    error: @handleError

handleError: (task, response) ->
  if response.status == 422
    errors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).errors
    for attribute, messages of errors
      alert "#{attribute} #{message}" for message in messages

#This should remove the selected task from the database
clear: (task) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  @collection.remove()
```

This might also help. Here's my task.js.coffee view:

```
class Backbonetodo.Views.Task extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['tasks/task']
  tagName: 'li'

render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template(task: @model))
  this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
markComplete: (event) ->
  # You need to get somehow specific task id
  # Example: id = $(event.currentTarget).data('id'), if you have the id in the DOM
  @collection.get(id).set(complete:true)

# You have here a parameter task which is actually event
clear: (task) ->
  event.preventDefault() # This is task :p
  # Same as before: get your task or task id
  # Example: 
  #  taskId = $(event.currentTarget).data('id')
  #  task = @collection.get(taskId)
  @collection.remove(task)
```

My examples depends on your template.

Suggestion: try to use `@$` instead of `$`, to scope elements to your view's element, by the way I used `$`